# How calculate sequential values based on group field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, field-calculator

In **field calculator** i calculate sequential values in field [ORDER_ID] 
What need change in script to calculate sequential values based on group field [GROUP_ID]. I select values manually and use autoincrement () in Field Calculator.

Parser: Python 
Expression: autoIncrement()
Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1
 pInterval = 1
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec
```

This is the result.
Field ORDER_ID is already calculated manually (i select GROUP_ID and use autoincrement).
[image]

[image]

What changes script needed to use it in field calculator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with an [UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) easily in the Python Window:

```
import arcpy

vals = []
fields = ['ORDER_ID', 'GROUP_ID'] #your field names
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(your_lyr, fields) as rows:
    for r in rows:
        vals.append(r[1])
        r[0] = vals.count(r[1])
        rows.updateRow(r)
```

where the  `your_lyr` variable is a reference to the table you're updating.

Comment: -1. This equal to simple autoincrement. OP specifically asks about groups

Comment: @FelixIP he's incrementing by the count for each group. I don't see what's wrong with his answer.

Comment: not exactly what I was asking. but it works. if I understand correctly numbering going by creation date/

Comment: @ian you are right. My mistake, i'll upvote it back as soon as i can. Misread count as len.

Comment: @Jannik - this is doing an increment by the value in your `GROUP_ID` field. So it should incremental counts for each group.  @ian - thanks for backing me up :)

Answer (score 1):

I realise this post is a little dated and with an already accepted answer, but the question specifically asked for alterations to the existing auto-increment codeblock for the field calculator, which should be achievable simply by using the GroupID as a variable to test.

Pre-logic script would be:

```
rec=0
group=1
def autoIncrement(GroupId):
 global rec
 global group
 pStart = 1
 pInterval = 1
 if (GroupId == group): 
  rec += pInterval 
 else: 
   group += pInterval
   rec = pStart
 return rec
```

And the expression:

```
autoIncrement(!GroupId!)
```

With the parser set to python. The assumptions are a) Your groups start at 1; and b) your groups are sequentially numbered.